# VueJS - [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-loader, vue-cli-3

I'm trying to make a vue component which is a wrapper for [Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/). 
But when I try to use this component into another component, I'm getting an error saying, 
`[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.`

[Link](https://github.com/93gaurav93/v-owl-carousel) to my github repo.

Here is how I'm using that component into another component,

```
import Carousel from 'v-owl-carousel'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Carousel
  }
}

<Carousel :autoplay="true">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?1">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?2">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?3">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?4">
</Carousel>
```

- [webpack.config.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/93gaurav93/v-owl-carousel/master/webpack.config.js)
- [.babelrc](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/93gaurav93/v-owl-carousel/master/.babelrc)
- [package.json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/93gaurav93/v-owl-carousel/master/package.json)
- [Carousel.vue](https://github.com/93gaurav93/v-owl-carousel/raw/master/src/Carousel.vue)
- [main.js](https://github.com/93gaurav93/v-owl-carousel/raw/master/src/main.js)

And here is the entire error trace,

```
log.js?1afd:24 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:587 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <Carousel>
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:587
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2754
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:7995
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4133
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5604
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5551
createChildren @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5678
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5580
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6087
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2656
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2784
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3138
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3127
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2791
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:7995
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4133
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5604
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5551
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6126
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2656
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2784
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3138
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3127
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2791
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:7995
(anonymous) @ main.js?56d7:6
./src/main.js @ app.js:1919
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:725
fn @ app.js:102
0 @ app.js:1932
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:725
(anonymous) @ app.js:792
(anonymous) @ app.js:795
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8010 Download the Vue Devtools extension for a better development experience:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools
```

Thanks.

Comment: The main.js needs to instantiate a Vue object. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 How do I specify component in it?